# Chartsjs 2 (Alpha) not working in IE8 (even with excanvas)

Tags: javascript, canvas, charts, chart.js

I'm using Charts.js version 2 last alpha and I can get it work in Chrome, Firefox and IE 9, but I can't do it work in IE8, even with excanvas loaded before the Charts.js library and my code for drawing the charts.

The first Charts js version was compatible with IE8, I think that the new version have this feature also. I'm wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is compatible.

I did used excanvas.js and es5-shim.js to give IE8 the tools to draw canvas and some javascript methods as foreach or map.

Also I did changed a bit the excanvas.js library... i just commented the above line:

```
this.textMeasureEl_.style.font = this.font;
```